# If statement in recursive call

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion

I have this function that traverse a tree structure that is represented in a nested dictionary.
The code return what i want, in this example it return [["Air Handler Unit", "Return Fan", "Command"]], but it also print "Point no found", that should not happen.

I have tried to debug and I have problem understanding. I thought that when I have a recursive call inside the for loop the recursive call will finish and then check the if statement after. But when I debug it looks like the if statement is checked every recursive call.,,

Anyone have a tips? Maybe the code is structured wrong in the first place or I dont truly understand how recursive call works. I guess the second, maybe both..

```py
def _find_path_to_main_system(system_struct, main_system_type, path = None, 
    found_main_paths = None):

    if path is None:
        path: List[str] = []
        found_main_paths = []

    for node in system_struct["sub_systems"]:
        current_path = path + [node["type"]]
        if node["type"] == main_system_type and current_path not in found_main_paths:
            found_main_paths.append(current_path)
        elif "sub_systems" in node:
            _find_path_to_main_system(node, main_system_type, current_path, found_main_paths)
    
    if len(found_main_paths)==0:
        print("Point no found")
        
    return found_main_paths

main_system_struct = {
        "type": "Building",
        "sub_systems": [
            {
                "type": "Air Handler Unit",
                "sub_systems": [
                    {"type": "Economizer", "sub_systems": [{"type": "Status", "friendly_name": "eco_status"}]},
                    {"type": "Return Fan", "sub_systems": [{"type": "Command", "friendly_name": "fan_command"}]},
                    {"type": "Supply Air Temperature Sensor", "friendly_name": "ahu_supply_temp"},
                ],
            }
        ],
    }

main_system_type="Command"
found_main_paths=_find_path_to_main_system(main_system_struct,main_system_type)
```

Comment: Every recursive function gets to a point where there's nothing more to be done.  You should just skip printing "Point no found", because you will ALWAYS get to that point eventually.

Comment: But what if the point does not exist in the main_system_struct? Then I want the ("Point no found") @TimRoberts

Comment: The function that calls `_find_path_to_main_system` can do `paths = _find_path_to_main_system(...); if paths == []: print('Point not found')`. In fact, it would be better. Function `_find_path_to_main_system` shouldn't call `print`. What if a program wants to use that function, but wants to handle errors internally without printing everything for the user to see?

Comment: The thing you are missing is that `find_path_to_main_system` gets called not only at the outer level, but for all of the inner levels, too.  If the point is not found, then the FINAL call will return an empty list, and it's up to the CALLER to diagnose it.  Not finding it in an inner level is perfectly normal.